# How to import file to a custom form with custom DAC in Acumatica

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

I am having trouble importing a CSV to my custom grid containing a custom DAC.

I have managed to get the import functionality and got the process to the point where it imports the first line in the file only. I cannot see why the caches only contain the one entry from the file.

My code:

Graph:

```
public class MyClassProcess : PXGraph<MyClassProcess>, PXImportAttribute.IPXPrepareItems
{
    [PXImport(typeof(MyDAC))]

    public PXSelect<MyDAC> CustomersView;      

    public MyClassProcess()
    {
        PXCache entry = CustomersView.Cache;

        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<MyDAC.id>(entry, null, false);

        entry.AllowInsert = true;
        entry.AllowUpdate = true;
        entry.AllowDelete = true;

    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable customersView()
    {
        List<MyDAC> list = new List<MyDAC>();

        foreach (MyDACitem in CustomersView.Cache.Inserted)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

DAC:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyDAC: IBqlTable
{
    #region Id

    public abstract class id : IBqlField { }
    protected int? _ID;
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ID")]
    public virtual int? ID { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Selected
    public abstract class selected : IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected bool? _Selected = false;
    [PXDBBool()]
    [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
    public virtual bool? Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return _Selected;
        }
        set
        {
            _Selected = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region CustomerID
    public abstract class customerID : IBqlField { }
    protected string _CustomerID;
    [PXDBString(20, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Account ID")]
    public virtual String CustomerID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region CustomerCD
    public abstract class customerCD : IBqlField { }
    protected string _CustomerCD;
    [PXDBString(50, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Account Name")]
    public virtual String CustomerCD { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region PaymentMethodID
    public abstract class paymentMethodID : IBqlField { }
    protected string _PaymentMethodID;
    [PXDBString(10, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Payment method")]
    public virtual String PaymentMethodID { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Cashaccount
    public abstract class cashaccount : IBqlField { }
    protected int? _CashAccount;
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Cashaccount")]
    public virtual int? Cashaccount { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Currency
    public abstract class currency : IBqlField { }
    protected string _Currency;
    [PXDBString(10, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Currency")]
    public virtual String Currency { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
<px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%"
    TypeName="MyNamespace.MyClassProcess"
    PrimaryView="CustomersView"
    >
    <CallbackCommands>

    </CallbackCommands>
</px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phL" runat="Server">
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Primary" AllowAutoHide="false">
    <Levels>
        <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="CustomersView">
            <Columns>
                <px:PXGridColumn Type="CheckBox" TextAlign="Center" DataField="Selected" Width="60" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ID" Width="90" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CustomerID" Width="90" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CustomerCD" Width="150" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="PaymentMethodID" Width="90" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Cashaccount" Width="90" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Currency" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                <%--<px:PXGridColumn DataField="CurrentBal" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>--%>
            </Columns>
        </px:PXGridLevel>
    </Levels>
    <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
    <ActionBar >
    </ActionBar>

<Mode AllowUpload="True" /></px:PXGrid>
```

Data:

ID,Account ID,Account Name,Payment method,Cashaccount,Currency ID

1,C001,Customer name 1,EFT,8405,ZAR

2,C002,Customer2,EFT,8405,ZAR

3,C003,Customer 3,EFT,8405,ZAR

All customers, payment methods, cashaccounts, currencies exist in the system.

I have a table named the same as MyDAC.

```
PXCache entry = CustomersView.Cache;
```

And

```
foreach (MyDACitem in CustomersView.Cache.Inserted)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
```

Only shows 1 line as inserted even if there are two lines in the file. It imports this one line successfully into my grid, but not the other lines.

What am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing an IsKey=true in your DAC ?

Comment: Still the same issue. I have amended code in original post

Comment: Are you supplying ID from the raw file? 
If so, you will want to make ID visible by commenting out this line: 

    //PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<MyDAC.id>(entry, null, false);

 
If not, is your ID field actually an Identity column in the database table?  
If true, replace PXDBInt with [PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)] 
for the ID property in the DAC.  

Also, to save records, add the following to offer buttons:

        public PXCancel<MyDAC> Cancel;
        public PXSave<MyDAC> Save;

Comment: To view actual saved records, consider changing your delegate select to:  
       
    List<MyDAC> list = new List<MyDAC>();

    PXSelectBase<MyDAC> cmd = new PXSelect<MyDAC>(this);

    foreach (MyDAC item in cmd.Select())
    {
         list.Add(item);
    }

    return list;

Comment: Lastly, your Selected column may not need to be stored in the DB table (?).  Consider changing it to PXBool  instead of PXDBBool and removing the field from your DB table.